# Inno setup subfolders with additional installation in "All Programs" list?

Tags: exe, inno-setup, drivers

I'm trying to create setup with Inno, I'm interested in how to add folder that will be shown as subfolder in programs directory in All Programs list. I'm planning to set some drivers in there, sho that user can start them manually from "All Programs" list, if they do not succeed to install automatically?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[Setup]
DefaultGroupName=MyCompanyName\MyAppName

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\MyNormalModeFunctionShortcut"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; WorkingDir: "{app}"
;this is default one
Name: "{group}\MySubfolderName\MySafeModeFunctionShortcut"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Parameters: "-safemode"; WorkingDir: "{app}"
;this one is placed in Subfolder
```